# Read file from notepad and put data In a table

Tags: sql-server-2012

Hi I am a PL/SQL developer and is looking some helping hand in SQL Server 2012 . I want to read a file from a notepad and write it into a Temporary table . Here is my code for PL/SQL :-

```
     Create or Replace PROCEDURE Rfile is
f UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
s VARCHAR2(200); 
BEGIN
f := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('C:\Projects\','testdatabinary.txt','R');
  IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(f) THEN
    LOOP
      BEGIN
        UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(f,s);
        IF s IS NULL THEN
          EXIT;
        END IF;
      INSERT INTO DATAINSERT
      (COLUMN1, COLUMN2)
      VALUES
      (s, 'testdatabinary');
      END;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
  END IF;
 END;
```

I am having two columns in my table say name and age which are holding the input coming from notepad file . 
This seems to work fine on SQLDeveloper but it is seems of no use due to missing packages and syntax in SQL Server . Can anyone help me up for this ? Providing the correct way to do the task being done in the above procedure for SQL SERVER 2012 ?? Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get everything from the text file:

```
DECLARE @asd NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @asd = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Text1.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) as Test)
PRINT @asd
```

Afterwords you can format it as you wish.